# Formal taxonomy for cryptographic vulnerabilities

Tags: terminology

There are several areas in which cryptographic vulnerabilities can be introduced.

Length extension attacks are inherent to hash functions using Merkle–Damgård.

Heartbleed was a vulnerability caused by the specific implementation of a protocol.

Using weak ciphers such as DES is a configuration issue.

Is there a formal taxonomy for issues such as this, to make communicating issues easier?

Comment: I would't call it formal, but [**CWE**](http://cwe.mitre.org/) is established, extensive, and fairly widely used.